# Command line serial terminal

Tags: eclipse, embedded, terminal, serial-port, microchip

I'm using Eclipse to develop application for embedded systems.

One of the options of Eclipse configurations are "Program to run after programming/building"

Usually, on that textbox it's the path to our .exe generated before, but on this case I want to run a serial port terminal, like this:

terminal -COM=9 -baud=9600...

My goal here it's to have that terminal printing on Eclipse console. Is that possible?

Comment: So what exactly is the question?  You can launch any executable you like from a command line.  What OS are you using? What terminal program do you wish to use?

Comment: I want to have a serial port terminal on the Console view of Eclipse. The provided solution do exactly that, but on a different tab (Terminal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Target Management](http://eclipse.org/tm/about.php) platform to achieve this result. Sadly, I did not try this, so cannot tell whether it works or not, but should be according to the about page.

Comment: You're right (I guess). Soemone made a plugin to make that steps easy(see Other plugins on https://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=toolchain:eclipse:install ), it's the best explanation I've found.